# Best place for Blender add-on user's manual

Tags: add-on, documentation

I am wondering if the current best format and place to put new Blender add-on user's manuals is as extension scripts in the blender wiki:

```
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/my_addon
```

or if this is outdated (it's still at v2.6) and there is a better standardized practice beyond html on our own website.

Thanks for your insights!